# question on how to achieve threading in c# for this scenario

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have this scenario where a windows service runs on the server. Every hour or so it reads a log file and saves the contents to db. 
Now, there are going to be three files and these must be read and saved to three different tables. (i will read these connection strings etc from config file) This can be achieved by threading I know. So I want to call the existing 'readfile' method in a thread.

Am not familiar with threading, but is this the way to go?

```
NameValueConfigurationCollection config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("LogDirectoryPath") as NameValueConfigurationCollection;  

            foreach (DictionaryEntry keyvalue in configs)
            {
               Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteProcess(keyvalue.Key.ToString())));
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();

            }


private void ExecuteProcess(string path)
      {
        var xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(path);
          XPathNavigator xPathNavigator = xPathDocument.CreateNavigator();

        string connectionString = GetXPathQuery(
            xPathNavigator,
            "/connectionString/@value");

        string commandText = GetXPathQuery(
            xPathNavigator,
            "/commandText/@value");

        string filePath = GetXPathQuery(
            xPathNavigator,
            "/filePath/@value");

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        ProcessFiles(sqlConnection, commandText, filePath);
}
```

Do I have to make the method static ? What about the variables used?

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4 you could leverage the Task Parallel Library for this, so you would not have to explicitly *create threads*, but just express *what code* you want to execute in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(configs.Select( x => x.Key.ToString()), path => ExecuteProcess(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to use [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for threads which I wish to run in parallel in a fire and forget scenario e.g. something like

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry keyvalue in configs)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        ExecuteProcess(keyvalue.Key.ToString());
    });
}
```

The [Parallel Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) library is also useful but not guaranteed to go parallel and instead [adapts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx), as I understand it, to the number of processors. It does however synchronise all your worker threads back again. So it depends on what it is you are trying to achieve,